# Extract items in nested lists

Tags: r, list, nested

i have a problem:
I work with a data frame with development time (dependent variable) of five species according to the Temperature (independent variable)
with a "by" function I calculated  lm's for all of the five species

```
by(dados, dados$Especie, function(dados) lm(dados$Tempo ~ dados$Temp, data = dados)
```

and as result I got lists nested in other lists as yo can see here

```
List of 5
 $ C.albiceps   :List of 12
  ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 262.78 -1.76
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "dados$Temp"
  ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:41] -4.157 -2.394 -0.631 1.131 2.894 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:41] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ effects      : Named num [1:41] -1344.031 -133.548 0.235 1.977 3.72 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:41] "(Intercept)" "dados$Temp" "" "" ...
  ..$ rank         : int 2
```

It's a list of 5 elements (one for each specie), and each specie is a list of 12 elements (from the lm function). So, 5 lists of 12, within a list of 5.

Now, my question:
I want to extract the values from my coefficients and sum them up. So I got 
List$speciesName$coefficients[2] and I want to extract each value (the second item of $coefficients, for each specie), and I also want to save it in a vector (in order do calculate indices with it).

Any helpful hints on that?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired result

Comment: Sorry for missing it, that's is R indeed, but nongkrong got it, thanks a lot : D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the models with an `apply` function and extract the coefficients with `coef`.

```
## Example
mods <- by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, function(x) lm(mpg ~ disp, data=x))

## Sum up all the second coefficients
sum(sapply(mods, function(x) coef(x)[[2]]))
```